# Error in local repository with Hashes of expected file

Tags: 18.04, mirrors, apt-mirror

I have a local repository with ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, however 18.04 is not working fine, we are using this source.list:

```
deb [ arch=amd64 trusted=yes ] http://das-repo.cimex.com.cu/Repositorios/ubuntu/bionic bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb [ arch=amd64 trusted=yes ] http://das-repo.cimex.com.cu/Repositorios/ubuntu/bionic-updates bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb [ arch=amd64 trusted=yes ] http://das-repo.cimex.com.cu/Repositorios/ubuntu/bionic-backports bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb [ arch=amd64 trusted=yes ] http://das-repo.cimex.com.cu/Repositorios/ubuntu/bionic-security bionic-security main restricted multiverse restricted
deb [ arch=amd64 trusted=yes ] http://das-repo.cimex.com.cu/Repositorios/ubuntu/bionic-proposed bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

And the error is the next:

```
Err:8 http://das-repo.cimex.com.cu/Repositorios/ubuntu/bionic-security bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  File has unexpected size (3541 != 204). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 172.22.29.45 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:204 [weak]
   - SHA256:c52cce5fb5a2a386224fe297d20e47786e11f72e7bcf3c2cf8ec6a54ca724315
   - SHA1:788fc9972a69cf1e84b2be50d7b0e05c3b67f58e [weak]
   - MD5Sum:85a92be526a2f6bed09a79e4b8f3adc3 [weak]
  Release file created at: Mon, 14 May 2018 13:29:23 +0000
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://das-repo.cimex.com.cu/Repositorios/ubuntu/bionic-security/dists/bionic-security/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  File has unexpected size (3541 != 204). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 172.22.29.45 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:204 [weak]
    - SHA256:c52cce5fb5a2a386224fe297d20e47786e11f72e7bcf3c2cf8ec6a54ca724315
    - SHA1:788fc9972a69cf1e84b2be50d7b0e05c3b67f58e [weak]
    - MD5Sum:85a92be526a2f6bed09a79e4b8f3adc3 [weak]
   Release file created at: Mon, 14 May 2018 13:29:23 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The script to update the repo was executed yesterday and everything was fine.

If I quit "main" from this line the repo work fine:

```
deb [ arch=amd64 trusted=yes ] http://das-repo.cimex.com.cu/Repositorios/ubuntu/bionic-security bionic-security main restricted multiverse restricted
```

How I can fix this problem?